# Doctrine - create model / entity dynamically

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How do I create entity dynamically in doctrine, based on abstract entity class? The tables names must differ. For example

```
// abstract entity model
class Transport {
   // $name, $type and other columns
}
```

And creation looks like:

```
class TransportManager {

public function registerTransport($name) {
$car = ...
// here create table $name if does not exist, 
// and if it exists then just
// return Car instance of this $name table
return $car;

}
```

usage:

```
$car = $transportManager->registerTransport('car');
$airplain = $transportManager->registerTransport('airplain');
$train = $transportManager->registerTransport('train');
$helicopter = $transportManager->registerTransport('helicopter');
```

reason? I have several (> 10) tables with the same structure and I want to keep all the data in separate tables to prevent orverloading of each table

Comment: What do you mean by "same structure"? Guess you can solve by composition of entities, rather than by inheritance.

Comment: I mean several tables, and same table schema, and yes, there is no need in inheritance

Comment: If you have same database schema, you have the same entity [with a different `transportType` field I guess]. If you want to have different tables with shared fields, look into [Doctrine Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

Comment: I cant user `transportType` field because want to have separate tables. I cant use ` Doctrine Inheritance Mapping` because I need to create tables dynamically, not manually

Comment: Seems bad design to me. Hard to test, and for instance what if you want to query for all the entities that match certain criteria across all tables? How do you know how many tables are there via Doctrine? I would just use composition - a common class, on which you inject additional components on demand.

Comment: @moonwave99, I cant use common table, because it will be too HUGE. in my case every dynamical table will contain directories (millions of rows with only `id` and `name` values). I cant store them in one table - the table will be too big and queries take lot of time. I can create each directory table manually, but there are a lot of tables (for now 20, will be increased in the future)  - so a lot of manual work, copy/paste and duplicate code. Dynamically created tables I think the right solution, but maybe I mistake. But I dont see any other better-design way

Comment: Well if you want _different_ tables with a lot of shared columns, you'll end up with duplicated code, but I guess that's the tradeoff. Consider [generating entities via console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html), it will be pretty fast to create new entities on the fly.

Comment: thank you, but the problem not only in generating entites, but also usage, interfaces, controllers, admin-panel for each entity and lot of other every-time duplicated code. I hopped to see another solution

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine supports inheritance: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

You may also batch generate the new entities, but it depends on your workflow
(e.g. create the code for new entities, generate the migrations, execute migrations etc.)

Comment: I already use inheritance, it reduces code, but still, I don't satisfied. Please read comments under my question

Answer (score 0):

Use one table. With proper indexing, it should not be slower than using multiple tables, even if it is huge.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this, although not exactly the approach you were trying:

```
$metadata = $cmf->getMetadataFor('YourBundle:Transport');
$metadata->setTableName('car');
//work with car
$metadata->setTableName('airplain');
//work with airplain
```

Hope it serves.